# Email not sending in azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, smtp, gmail, azure-web-app-service

I have configured my application in Azure web apps. I am sending the mail using smtp server. The outlook is sending emails properly. Other mail providers like(Gmail) are not sending emails. Please help.

Comment: gmail blocks account access from a different IP, location. you might need to enable access to the same. refer -
 https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

> Other mail providers like(Gmail) are not sending emails
>   You could check the providers that have policy to allow to do that.

Take gmail for example, as  Ankit Kumar mentioned that you need to turn **Allow less secure apps:** on for your gmail account.

[image]

I also test it on my side, it works correctly. The following is my demo code.

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Tom Gmail", "xx@gmail.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Tom Hotmail", "xxx@hotmail.com"));
message.Subject = "I am a mail subject";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
{
       Text = "I am a mail body."
};

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{

  client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
  // Note: since we don't have an OAuth2 token, disable
  // the XOAUTH2 authentication mechanism.
  client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
  // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
  client.Authenticate("sunguiguan@gmail.com", "@WSX3edc");
  client.Send(message);
  client.Disconnect(true);
  }
```

We also could use SendGrid on the Azure,more detail please refer to [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email)